# How to Justify labels + input box to the right/left?

Tags: html, css, text-justify

I'm building a basic interest rate calculator but can't seem to get my inputs to display the way I want them to.

I'm brand new to HTML/CSS/Javascript and I feel heavily gated by lack of references so forgive me if any practices are a little outdated.

here is my base code for my entries:

```
<div class="entryform">
      <ul>

        <label for="int">Interest Rate: </label>
        <input type="number" id="InterestInput" name="int">
        <br>

        <label for="beg">Beginning Price: </label>
        <input type="number" id="BeginningPrice" name="beg">
        <br>

        <label for="end">Ending Price: </label>
        <input type="number" id="InterestInput" name="int">
        <br>

        <label for="int">n (days, months, years...): </label>
        <input type="number" id="InterestInput" name="int">

      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is my css code:

```
.entryform {...}
```

I've tried justify-content, align-items, flex... I feel like I'm going crazy.

[Sample visual of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Klj.png)

I just want to make the inputs line up with eachother on the right side,  Thank you so much for your time/help!

Comment: Use a grid layout like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) or use [Tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid `ul` can only have `li` as children

Answer (score -2):

One possible solution:

Give the labels display: inline-block;

Give them a fixed width

Align text to the right

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="entryform">
      <ul>

        <label for="int">Interest Rate: </label>
        <input type="number" id="InterestInput" name="int">
        <br>

        <label for="beg">Beginning Price: </label>
        <input type="number" id="BeginningPrice" name="beg">
        <br>

        <label for="end">Ending Price: </label>
        <input type="number" id="InterestInput" name="int">
        <br>

        <label for="int">n (days, months, years...): </label>
        <input type="number" id="InterestInput" name="int">

      </ul>
    </div>
```